# cómo hacer más rápido un datalist?

Tags: html5

Tengo una pregunta sobre cómo optimizar un `datalist` con 2000 items ya que cuando está activo y se intenta escribir en el input, el proceso es lento, se traba demasiado. 
Cabe destacar que lo realizó con una petición `ajax`, cuando inicia la página, no creo que la petición sea el problema, también implementar los ítems desde php, y sigo teniendo el mismo problema ¿habrá otra alternativa?
¿sería buena idea usar una librería? (como `ace`)
[image: Input con datalist]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de valores tiene del `datalist`?¿Podrías poner un ejemplo? No hace falta que sean 2000 items, solo unos cuantos

Comment: claro: "<option value='23-12ht-121'></option>" sería algo así, son 2000 options los que tengo en el datalist

Comment: deberías agregar código para ver que estás haciendo y como podría resolverte. Igual, no se puede paginar, para que se presenten una menor cantidad de items

Comment: de acuerdo, solo es un datalist con un input, ya está en la pregunta, cabe destacar que son 2020 options

Answer (score 1):

Te refieres por **optimizar** a hacer que cargue más rápido.

La cantidad de elementos o más bien la página y su peso solo se ve afectado por el rendimiento de la computadora del cliente y la velocidad de su Internet.

Así que no importa la cantidad de elementos.

Comment: Si, a eso llegue (la computadora del usuario) gracias c: